# Customizing atom package snippets

Tags: laravel, syntax, atom-editor

I downloaded a Laravel syntax package for Atom (atom-laravel).
The tiny problem I just discovered, is that when I trigger "section", the output is:

```
@section('...')
@endsection
```

Now, I've read, that `@endsection` is outdated since Laravel 4. The proper directive to use is now `@stop`

How can I customize the package, for that trigger to return:

```
@section('...')
@stop
```

Is there a file I can modify to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `Settings -> Packages` in Atom, you can click the Package and then `View Code`, which opens a new Atom instance with the downloaded package. Any changes you make will be instantaneous after you save.

Specifically you're looking for `/snippets/laravel.cson` file, and I think the `section` directive, which is line `628`.

Edit: According to my copy of `atom-laravel`, which I just downloaded, the snippet should be outputting `stop`:

```
 section:
    prefix: "section"
    body: '''
      @section('${1:name}')
        $2
      @${3|stop,show,overwrite|}
```

Comment: I've checked my code, and It looks exactly the same on my machine. What I discovered, is that the trigger uses the syntax from the other package that I have (language-blade) which returns @endsection. Should I just modify the other one, the way you described, and delete the section code from language-blade?

Comment: @manjii If `language-blade` is conflicting with `atom-laravel`, you might not be able to have both installed. I'd recommend either removing `language-blade` or modifying `language-blade` so it no longer outputs the `@endsection`, allowing `atom-laravel` to do its job. Consider raising an issue on `language-blade`'s GitHub and let them know that blade is interfering with laravel like that.

Comment: I disabled the language-blade package for now but I don't really know how to toggle the atom-laravel syntax on now. WIth language-blade I just had to choose "Blade" in the bottom-right corner of atom editor and I don't see any name related to atom-laravel syntax. BTW, reported an issue on language-blade GitHib, as you recommended.

Comment: @manjii Laravel's code snippets should appear when you start typing in a PHP file. I am surprised that the two plugins didn't work together, as [this link](http://www.mybelovedphp.com/2015/06/30/laravel-5-1-development-with-the-atom-editor/) recommends using `language-blade` with `atom-laravel`. Perhaps revert to your original idea of editing `language-blade` instead?

Comment: Updated it. Works fine. Although I wonder what causes the atom-laravel syntax not to appear in the editor. But that's a different problem. I appreciate your help.